# How to make TriStateTreeView with VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'd like to make TreeView with TriState CheckBox in Vb.net,

I've been making a new Class named TriStateTreeView and Inherits TreeView,
then I just stucked :(

The TreeView class has TreeNode and TreeNodeCollection property,
and they also have Add or Checked methods.

I couldn't even get the CheckBox object in TreeNodes.
Should I override them with TriStateNode and TriStateTreeNodeCollection etc?

Thanks for any advise.
It'll be appreciated with someone could post some Example with VB.net

Comment: First you can have a watch at this [**msdn page**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.checkboxes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for comment.The page seems to have only the way to control the TreeView and check all the Child Nodes. How could I make the third state in CheckBox like BLOCK or DOT?

Comment: .net doesn't support it natively. There are some good tutorial like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/59514/Simple-Tri-State-TreeView) and other similar questions, but they're all for c#...

Comment: Thanks for comment.Hmm...I've seen other example with C# too, but some class seems to be not exist in VB.net. Is it impossible?

Comment: Yes.. C# has more power, and not all classes and functions can be translated. I think you can use the c# control in your vb code, but I've never done that before!

Comment: (Consider to switch to c# coding for the next developments: I've done that last year, and I'll never go back to vb!)

Comment: Okay...I'll keep trying.Thanks for comments.